# What right hand side of the statement is doing?

Tags: rust, stm32, stm32f4discovery

After blinking the LEDs. I started with the chapter register and on the first page itself I got some issues. I read about most of them and find out that the address is const and to use that fixed value we used raw pointer GPIOE_BSRR as *mut u32 which is making a copy of the address(referencing) variable and allowing us to change.
Second, we are dereferencing using * and putting the statement inside the unsafe block as per the raw pointer deference rules..

I hope till here i am getting it right now the next issue is what we are doing at right-hand side using the shift operator. We are using 9 11 to set and 16, 25 to reset **but why 1 in every shift?**

```
  #![no_main]
#![no_std]

#[allow(unused_imports)]
use aux7::{entry, iprint, iprintln};

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
aux7::init();

{
// A magic address!
const GPIOE_BSRR: u32 = 0x48001018;

    // Turn on the "North" LED (red)
    //we use the dereference operator * on a raw pointer that requires an unsafe block.
    //change data through the mutable pointer
    (GPIOE_BSRR as *mut u32) = 1 << 9;

    // Turn on the "East" LED (green)
    *(GPIOE_BSRR as *mut u32) = 1 << 11;

    // Turn off the "North" LED
    (GPIOE_BSRR as *mut u32) = 1 << (9 + 16);

    // Turn off the "East" LED
    (GPIOE_BSRR as *mut u32) = 1 << (11 + 16);
}
loop {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing 1 to GPIO BSRR sets or resets a bit in GPIO ODR.  Writing 0 does nothing. See [RM0090](http://file:///tmp/mozilla_tcv0/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) section 8.4.7.

Comment: Ohh ya, I missed that yes it is writing to ODR register for 1 and 0. I have one more issue. Is it this simple to write and set, reset? How this shifting is actually working with the address? 1<<9 at GPIOE_BSRR

Answer (score 0):

1 is used to set and reset bits, that's why we are using 1 for both turning the LED on and off.
**1 << 9** means we performing left shift operation here.
For eg: we have 32 bits (0000....0) right. 0 means low voltage to every bit, now to turn on LD3 (RED LED) which sits at pin 9 we are providing a high voltage to it using 1 (because 1 is used to set and reset both), similarly to turn that led off we are performing **1 << 25** because the reset bit of pin 9 is 25(9+16)and again 1 is used to reset the pin.

For more info, you can read the reference manual of the discovery board.
https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00043574-stm32f303xb-c-d-e-stm32f303x6-8-stm32f328x8-stm32f358xc-stm32f398xe-advanced-arm-based-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf#page=240&zoom=100,89,117

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is more clear now.